# Applying the same row id based on partition of ROW_NUMBER

Tags: t-sql, numbers, row

I'm trying to sequentially add number rows based on the DOC value - the only condition i have is that IF the document is the same (like three last rows) it should get the same row number.

```
SELECT [DOC], ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY [DOC] ORDER BY [DOC])
FROM [rowset_TST]
```

After i get excactly the opposite - the last three docs which are the same are numbered and the rest not: ZZB which is not unique should get the same row number.

```
ABC 1 DBS   1 DDS   1 SBC   1
SSC 1 ZZB   1 ZZB   2 ZZB   3
```

Any advice highly appreciated - please tell me if this would be doable with ROW_NUMBER()

Regards, Luke

Comment: Can you add more sample data to your question?  I don't even understand why you think you need row number here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend to use a rank function here, possibly `DENSE_RANK`:

```
SELECT [DOC], DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [DOC])
FROM [rowset_TST]
ORDER BY [DOC];
```

This would generate the following output, assuming your same sample data:

[image]

This is the only interpretation of your question/requirement which came to mind and makes any sense.  If you really want every doc, whether occurring one or more times, to have a "row number" value of 1, then I don't see the point in using `ROW_NUMBER`.